# Android grid gallery view error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gridview

i'm currently trying to get an grid based gallery view working on one of my fragments and i'm getting these errors

```
Error:(25, 20) error: onCreate(Bundle) in GalleryFragment cannot override onCreate(Bundle) in Fragment
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
Error:(28, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
Error:(30, 39) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
Error:(31, 43) error: incompatible types: GalleryFragment cannot be converted to Context
```

Any Ideas how to fix? The tutorial I followed seemed to be aimed at making this in an activity im not sure if that makes a difference. Thanks

```
package com.test.test.app;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context)
        {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            items.add(new Item("Image 1", R.drawable.image_1));
            items.add(new Item("Image 2", R.drawable.image_2));
            items.add(new Item("Image 3", R.drawable.image_3));
            items.add(new Item("Image 4", R.drawable.image_4));
            items.add(new Item("Image 5", R.drawable.image_5));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i)
        {
            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i)
        {
            return items.get(i).drawableId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
        {
            View v = view;
            ImageView picture;
            TextView name;

            if(v == null)
            {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
                v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
                v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
            }

            picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
            name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

            Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

            picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
            name.setText(item.name);

            return v;
        }

        private class Item
        {
            final String name;
            final int drawableId;

            Item(String name, int drawableId)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.drawableId = drawableId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does make a difference, if you are just starting with android it'll be easier for you to just do this in an activity and not in fragment

Comment: @Sourabh I know but its for a piece of work and for the navigation drawer fragments seemed the best route to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can move your code from fragment to activity or replace your onCreate with this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man this got rid of my errors. the app crashed out now but one step at a time. Know any good resources on making a simple grid gallery view for a noob?

Comment: A simple google search gives me [this](http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) which looks good but doesn't use a fragment :P

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` doesn't provide `context`. Thus you can't use this:

```
gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
```

It should be:

```
gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));
```

NOTE: It is not safe to get activity context by `getActivity` in `onCreate` or `onCreateView` of `Fragment` as `activity` might not be yet created. Try to call it from `onActivityCreated`.